# cat() returning undesired list when using tapply

Tags: r, cat, tapply

When I run this code:

```
a <- mtcars[,c("gear", "qsec")]
c <- tapply(a[,2], a[,1], length)
sapply(rownames(c), function(x) cat("Gear", x, "contains",  c[x], "qsec\n"))
```

I would like to get this:

```
Gear 3 contains 15 qsec
Gear 4 contains 12 qsec
Gear 5 contains 5 qsec
```

But I get this:

```
Gear 3 contains 15 qsec
Gear 4 contains 12 qsec
Gear 5 contains 5 qsec
$`3`
NULL

$`4`
NULL

$`5`
NULL
```

Where does the last part come from and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: I like both answers below. Just to add to those: `cat` prints on the screen, but `sapply` has to return a value because it is a function, therefore you get both as Roland said. `invisible` is a good technique to get rid of seeing the output as Akrun mentions below. Another way would be to save the output of the function in a variable so that it won't show on screen:   `a<-sapply(rownames(c), function(x) cat("Gear", x, "contains",  c[x], "qsec\n"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap it with `invisible` so that the list elements don't get printed in the R console.

```
invisible(sapply(rownames(c), 
     function(x) cat("Gear", x, "contains",  c[x], "qsec\n")))
Gear 3 contains 15 qsec
Gear 4 contains 12 qsec
Gear 5 contains 5 qsec
```

Comment: accepted because it answers the question applies to other situations

Answer (score 2):

`lapply` (and, consequently, `sapply`) has a return value constructed from the return values of the function calls (`NULL` in your example) within the loop. If you don't want return values and only want side effects like printing or plotting, you should use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you don't need a loop (neither *apply nor for) to do that:

```
> cat(paste("Gear", rownames(c), "contains", c, "qsec", collapse = "\n"))
Gear 3 contains 15 qsec
Gear 4 contains 12 qsec
Gear 5 contains 5 qsec
```